# At what percentage of platform usage should I design the specific experience for?

Tags: ipad, apple

At what percentage of platform usage should I design the specific experience for?

I have an app in the store now -

1% using from iPad

99% using from iPhone

So at what percentage should I start designing a specific experience for the iPad?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Try elaborating on your question or try asking it differently.

Comment: I have iphone app now
and when i check statistics i find 1% use app from ipad
so this is the time to start develop ipad app or what is the percentage ?

Comment: Well, it technically depends on what 1% of your audience amounts to. If say 1% of your audience amounts to 10 users, I won't bother much. But if the same 1% amounts to say 2000 users, I might give it a thought.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would like to know **why** it's primarily used on the iPhone and not the iPad. Is it because your users use the app on the go and they don't carry around their iPad? Or is it because the app doesn't look good scaled up on the iPad and scares off users?
This might tell me what actions I need to take.

If the app just has no use case on the iPad, developing it for iPad might be a waste of resources.
If the iPad app just doesn't deliver the same experience is does on the iPhone (because it's scaled up to fit the larger screen) then it might be worthwhile.

I've never heard of a platform usage percentage as a threshold for deciding about the development of an app. I think you need to weigh the potential gain against any development costs.

Signs for potential gain might be a bigger abandonment rate on the ipad, a smaller retention rate (poor engagement) and a bigger difference between product page pageviews and downloads.
If iPad scores worse than iPhone on these metrics, you can be sure there is some gain to be achieved.